# How do I dynamically wrap image in a div that doesn't move the image regardless of it's alignment?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a pin button, but in some instances the wrapper that this makes around the image is throwing off the alignment of the image itself. Is there a way to adjust this wrapper so that whether the image is floated left, right, center, being pulled out the edge of the content area, etc., the wrapper will not move the image from where it was before the wrapper was added.

```
(function(jQuery){

//Attach this new method to jQuery
jQuery.fn.extend({ 

    pinit: function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            wrap: '<span class="sw-pinit"/>',
            pageURL: document.URL
        } ;

        var options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
        var o = options; 

        //Iterate over the current set of matched elements
        return this.each(function() {

            var e = jQuery(this),
                pi_media = e.data('media') ? e.data('media') : e[0].src,
                pi_url = o.pageURL,
                pi_desc = e.attr('title') ? e.attr('title') : e.attr('alt'),
                pi_isvideo = 'false';
                bookmark = 'http://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media=' + encodeURI(pi_media) + '&url=' + encodeURI(pi_url) + '&is_video=' + encodeURI(pi_isvideo) + '&description=' + encodeURI(pi_desc);

            var eHeight = e.outerHeight();
            var eWidth = e.outerWidth();

            if(eHeight > 200 && eWidth > 100) {

                    e.wrap(o.wrap);
                    e.after('<span class="sw-pinit-overlay" style="height: ' + eHeight + 'px"><a href="' + bookmark + '" class="sw-pinit-button sw-pinit-'+swp_pinit_v_location+' sw-pinit-'+swp_pinit_h_location+'">Pin</a></span>');

                jQuery('.sw-pinit .sw-pinit-button').on('click', function () {
                    window.open(jQuery(this).attr('href'), 'Pinterest', 'width=632,height=253,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=1,scrollbars=1');               
                    return false;
                });

                jQuery('.sw-pinit').mouseenter(function () {
                    jQuery(this).children('.sw-pinit-overlay').fadeIn(200);
                }).mouseleave(function () {
                    jQuery(this).children('.sw-pinit-overlay').fadeOut(200);
                });
            };

        });

    }

});

})(jQuery);
```

And the CSS:

```
.sw-pinit{position:relative;display:inline-block;padding:0;}
.sw-pinit .sw-pinit-overlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:200;text-align:center;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);display:none;padding:0;}
a.sw-pinit-button{background:#cd2029;color:#fff;border:1px solid #aa1b29;font-size:20px;border-radius:4px;position:absolute;line-height:1;padding:10px 30px;}
a.sw-pinit-button:before{color:#fff;font-family:sw-icon-font;content:'b';margin-right:10px;margin-left:-5px;font-size:24px;float:left;line-height:1;}
a.sw-pinit-button:hover{background:#aa1b29;}
.sw-pinit-left{left:30px;}
.sw-pinit-center{left:50%;margin-left:-40px;}
.sw-pinit-right{right:30px;}
.sw-pinit-top{top:30px;}
.sw-pinit-middle{top:50%;margin-top:-16px;}
.sw-pinit-bottom{bottom:30px;}
```

Comment: `.sw-pinit { padding: 0; border: 0 none transparent; margin: 0; }`

Comment: I already have all of those in the CSS. In some instances, the images are centered or have negative margin to pull them to one side or another.

Comment: You should include the CSS, in your case it's relevant.

Comment: I just added it. But please bear in mind that this needs to be dynamic to account for any image layout so the solution, I'm guessing, is in the jQuery.

Comment: Is `<span class="sw-pinit"/>` the element you are iterating over? (i.e. `e`).